# Jquery window.width if/ doesnt working

Tags: jquery, scroll, window, width

Can someone tell why this script is not working? This script tries to add classes after scroll according to window width. I dont know where i'm making mistake. Anyone?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var nav = $('nav');
    var ul = $('ul.navigation li');
    var width = $(window).width();

    function nav() {
        if (width < 700) {
            navbar1();
        } else {
            navbar2();
        }
    };

    function navbar1() {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scroll > 10) {
                nav.addClass('scroll');
                ul.addClass('scroll');
            } else {
                nav.removeClass('scroll');
                ul.removeClass('scroll');
            }
        });
    }

    function navbar2() {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll > 10) {
                nav.addClass('scroll');
            } else {
                nav.removeClass('scroll');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you add html and css?

Comment: Can you please provide JSFiddle Demo?

Answer (score 0):

here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/ggozdyra/hLazq8c7/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var nav = $('nav');
    var ul = $('ul.navigation li');
    var width = $(window).width();

function kupa(){

   if ( width < 700) {  
        navbar1();
   } else {
        navbar2();
   };  
};

function navbar1() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if ( scroll > 10) {
            nav.addClass('scroll');
            ul.addClass('scroll');
        } else {
            nav.removeClass('scroll');
            ul.removeClass('scroll');
        }
    });
}

function navbar2() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if ( scroll > 10) {
            nav.addClass('scroll');
        } else {
            nav.removeClass('scroll');
        }
    });
  }

});
```